# Does USMT work to transfer from Win 7 to Win 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-7-backup

So I am trying to use USMT to transfer a Domain profile from a Win 7 computer to a Win 10 computer.  I have tried to use `USMT>scanstate \\network\mystore /ui:domain:user` from the Windows 8.1 ADK on the Win 7, this creates the .mig without error.  Then I am using the Windows 10 ADK's loadstate on the new computer `USMT>loadstate \\network\mystore`, this seems to have created the user's folders in C:\users apparently without error but has not migrated any of their favorites or desktop.

This is basically a clean profile, I have just put some shortcuts in Favorites and Desktop on the 1 user.  It creates about a 33Mb .mig file.  I have loads of local junk on my profile's desktop, ie a 40GB folder.  When I did a `USMT>scanstate \\network\mystore /auto` on my computer the .mig file jumped to 400MB quite quickly.

Title question, plus should I try the `/auto` and see what happens?  The only reason I didn't go through with it on my computer is right now I am testing this on my bosses computer with my profile.  The next time I will have to do this, I will doing it for a 1 user computer so I am thinking about just trying the `/auto`.

PS My backup plan is just to manually pull the files across.  This will be happening on a lot of computers but not all at once.  I'd just like to get ahead of the game and automate as much as possible.

Comment: As an example, the following line configures USMT to migrate only domain user profiles and not profiles from the local SAM account database: ScanStateArgs=/ue:*\* /ui:CONTOSO\*.....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/refresh-a-windows-7-computer-with-windows-10

Comment: I'll try it, some other tickets have taken priority so I may or may not get to it today.

Comment: I still have not been able to get to this.  I will finally be getting my Win 10 PC this week so I will be able to thoroughly test this.

Answer (score 0):

USMT does migrate directly from Win7 to win 10.

But do use Ehlertech's GUI for USMT. you will save so much time!